# Why is this multiprocessing.Pool stuck?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

CODE:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
print ('parent')
max_processes = 4
def foo(result):
    print (result)
def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=max_processes)
    while True:
        pool.apply_async(foo, 5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

'parent' gets printed 5 times, so initial pools were created. But there was no execution from print(result) statement.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid call to `.apply_async()` - the args are supposed to be supplied as a tuple, not directly as parameters to this method.  I think the only reason you're not getting an error is that you never call `.get()` on the returned value in order to retrieve the result of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the arguments incorrectly in your call to `apply_async`. The arguments need to be in a tuple (or other sequence, maybe), but you're passing `5` as a bare number.

Try:

```
def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=max_processes)
    while True:
        pool.apply_async(foo, (5,)) # make a 1-tuple for the args!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `with Pool(processes=max_processes) as pool:`

```
with Pool(processes=max_processes) as pool:
    while True:
        pool.apply_async(foo, 5)
    ...
```

> Warning multiprocessing.pool objects have internal resources that need to be properly managed (like any other resource) by using the pool as a context manager or by calling close() and terminate() manually. Failure to do this can lead to the process hanging on finalization.